# asp EntityDataSource detailsview OnItemUpdating e.cancel

Tags: asp.net

I will explain my problem.
So I have an asp page with 2 entityDataSource.
- The first one is used to fill my obout table:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" ContextTypeName="RichDataBusinessApplication.Web.RichDataEntities" EnableFlattening="false" EnableInsert="true" 
    EnableUpdate="true" EnableDelete="true" EntitySetName="UserInformations" runat="server" />
```

My obout table is in an updatepanel. When I want to edit a row in my table, this method is handled:

```
protected void Button_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
  SelectedUserHiddenField.Value = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
  UsersCustomerDetailsView.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.Edit);
  OpenPopupDialog(String.Format("#{0}", UpdatePopupPanel.ClientID));
}
```

The function OpenPopupDialog open a jquery popup dialog with the informations of my user I can now edit:

```
    <asp:Panel ID="UpdatePopupPanel" runat="server" CssClass="popup-dialog">
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional">
               <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="UsersGrid" EventName="Select" />
               </Triggers>
               <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:DetailsView runat="server" ID="UsersCustomerDetailsView" DataSourceID="SelectedUserDataSource2" DefaultMode="Edit" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" AutoGenerateRows="false"
OnItemUpdating="UserDetailsView_ItemUpdating" OnItemUpdated="UserDetailsView_ItemUpdated"
OnItemCommand="UserDetailsView_ItemCommand"
DataKeyNames="UserId" Width="100%">
                        <Fields>
                              <asp:TemplateField>
                                     <HeaderTemplate>
                                             <uc:CulturalLabel ID="CulturalLabel1" runat="server" Text="Lastname" />
                                     </HeaderTemplate>                     
                                     <EditItemTemplate>
                                           <asp:TextBox ID="LNameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Lastname") %>' CssClass="textEntry" ValidationGroup="CoordonneValidationGroupUp"/>
                                           <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="CustomRequieredValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="LNameTextBox" CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="test" ValidationGroup="CoordonneValidationGroupUp">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                     </EditItemTemplate>
                              </asp:TemplateField>
                         </Fields>
                   </asp:DetailsView>
            </ContentTemplate>
     </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>
```

The second EntityDataSource allow to fill the fields of my popup of my detailsview is this one:

```
    <asp:EntityDataSource ID="SelectedUserDataSource2" ContextTypeName="RichDataBusinessApplication.Web.RichDataEntities" EnableFlattening="false" EnableInsert="true" EnableUpdate="true" EnableDelete="true" EntitySetName="UserInformations" runat="server" AutoGenerateWhereClause="True">
      <WhereParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="UserId" ControlID="SelectedUserHiddenField" DbType="Guid" PropertyName="value" />
      </WhereParameters>
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

When I clic  on the update button of my popup I handled the "OnItemUpdating" of my detailsview:

```
    protected void UserDetailsView_ItemUpdating(Object sender, DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs e){
     Page.Validate("CoordonneValidationGroupUp");
     if (Page.IsValid)
     {
       //code to execute if page is valid
     }
     else
     {
       e.cancel = true;
     }
}
```

The problem is the following:
When my page is not valid because of the lastname is blank, "e.cancel=true" is executed but the "*" and error message don't appear and the field of my popup is reloaded with the data of the first row in my database.

So, if someone can help me!

Thanks!